# How do I have a Python 3.11.5 process suspend itself on Monterey 12.6.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, macos-monterey

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import time

os.system('/bin/kill -19 ' + str(os.getpid()))
time.sleep(2)
```

On Linux this script returns immediately, suspended. On Mac this script waits for two seconds and exits without suspending itself.

What can I do to make the suspension behavior available on Mac?

TIA,

Comment: what does `19` mean in context of IPC signal? I have never seen this being used before and my first assumption is this might not be supported under MacOs.

Comment: alternative would be `f"/bin/kill -s SIGSTOP - {os.getpid()}"`

Comment: @BijayRegmi "-s SIGSTOP": Thank you; could you restate your comment as an answer so I can accept it?" Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPC Signal `19` seems to be not supported in MacOS. You can use `-s SIGSTOP` to suspend the process.

```
import os
import time

os.system(f'/bin/kill -s SIGSTOP {os.getpid()}')
time.sleep(2)
```